# What is wrong with my attempt to create a Glassfish server available at Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I am trying to integrate Glassfish server support to an already existing eclipse java (maven) project. IMore precisely, I am looking into JMS and queues. I have completed a tutorial wih NetBeans, due to lack of success in Eclipse, but as my skills and familiarity with Eclipse are a lot better, I would really like to make it work there too.

I've tried a lot of different, but similar tutorials, and here is what happens in all of them:

**1. Download Glassfish Tools for eclipse.** As far as I can tell, this is done:

[image]

**2. Create new server, if not existing.** No servers available. No Glassfish option available.

[image] 


**3. Try Downloading additional server adapters.** Still no glassfish options...

[image]

None of the tutorials available seems to deal with this scenario. And they are all dependent on completing these steps. I am in the dark here. Any idea of what my problem might be? I am behind company firewall. There might be proxy-settings involved in this issue, but I have not been able to find the right concepts to explore if that is the case.

Comment: Could you post the exact version of Eclipse you are using, which Eclipse package you started with, and your Java version (as reported in the Eclipse about box). I was not able to reproduce the issue you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If it still doesn't work for you (2014.10.07) use the following link to install GlassFish 7.2 (with Eclipse's `Install New Software` mechanism):

http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.3.1/luna/repository

The one from the marketplace is 7.3, and it is broken for now.

[Courtesy of Jan Kowalski](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/821156/#msg_num_9)

Answer (score 0):

A new version of GlassFish Tools (7.3.0.201409251743) was released recently, which seems to be broken. There is [this](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21218) bug report, and I myself experienced buggy behavior after upgrading my installed version, too, like not being able to start the server anymore.

This is very annoying because apparently one can't revert to the previous version anymore either:

```
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish,7.2.1.201407111426
```

Comment: Hmmm... I need to check this out further. For now, I have switched to a JBOSS server instead, for testing purposes. I haven't completely figured that one out either, but I've gotten a lot further than I did with my GlassFish attempts.

Comment: Others have problems now, too, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157539/define-a-new-server-choosing-glassfish-3-1-gives-internal-error-eclipse-luna

Comment: The question is regarding GF Tools on Kepler, which is unrelated to recent issues on Luna (now fixed). I was not able to reproduce any issues on Kepler.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem at first when using the GlassFish Tools or the OEPE downloads (both deliver the same version) via Eclipse Marketplace. The installation runs smoothly, but no GlassFish option when adding a new server.

I'm running Kepler SR2 and Java 6 update 45.

Then, when browsing the Oracle site for OEPE, I found that the latest few versions are for Java 7/8. Via the archive page for OEPE http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-archive-1716547.html
I downloaded version 12.1.2.3 which is the last one for Kepler and Java 6.
With this version, the GlassFish option in the New Server dialog finally turned up.

Took me a few hours to find out. It's a bit disappointing that there were no error messages in neither the Eclipse UI nor in de Eclipse log.

(No comments on me using an old JDK please :-) I'll upgrade in the near future.