# Define a New Server choosing GlassFish 3.1 gives Internal Error - Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, glassfish

I have downloaded Eclipse Luna -4.4 version & plugin Glass-fish also i setup [GlassFish Tool](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools-luna#.VC0FQxbCczw)

Problem is I couldn't setup GlassFish Server

Where : Server - >Glass Fish (4/3.1) ->Click Next -> I got internal error. It goes to Next screen that contain , Define GlassFish run-time properties  & internal error

I Google it, i couldn't find proper solution for that

please help me out from this

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120899/what-is-wrong-with-my-attempt-to-create-a-glassfish-server-available-at-eclipse - it's apparently broken.

Answer (score 3):

If it still doesn't work for you (2014.10.07) use the following link to install GlassFish 7.2 (with Eclipse's `Install New Software` mechanism):

http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.3.1/luna/repository

The one from the marketplace is 7.3, and it is broken for now.

[Courtesy of Jan Kowalski](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/821156/#msg_num_9)

Comment: @Victor2748 You have to use the link with Eclipse, from `Install New Software`. Does it work from there?

Answer (score 0):

Google tools for Luna seem to be broken. I filed a bug at GlassFish JIRA, but no response so far:
https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21218?filter=-2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. We have fixed the "GlassFish Tools for Luna" entry on Eclipse Marketplace. Please try installing again.

In the future, you will get a more expedient response to questions regarding GlassFish Tools for Eclipse, but posting on the following forum:

https://community.oracle.com/community/java/java_development_tools/application_development_in_java/enterprise_pack_for_eclipse

Comment: in what way was it fixed? 7.3 still seem broken

Comment: Make sure to install all features that are offered under "GlassFish Tools for Luna" entry in Eclipse Marketplace. If you don't install "Oracle Java EE Tools", GF Tools will now work.

Comment: It still doesn't work with 7.3 and newest Eclipse Luna. Happy new year :)

Comment: There was an unrelated glitch in the rollout of 12.1.3.3.1 (7.3.3) that you may have ran into. The issue has been corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue with Glass fish server and Eclipse Luna. When i try to define a new server in eclipse and select Glassfish 4 and click next it takes me to screen for "define glassfish runtime properties" and a message Internal error